# What are the coefficients of the end value for the Runge-Kutta 3 (RK3) method in python

Tags: python, time, runge-kutta

Sorry if I have worded this question badly, maybe if someone can suggest better phrasing and I will change accordingly.

So, In terms of RK4, timestepping with x_old as initial x value for a time t, we have;

```
x_new = x_old + (1.0/6) * dt * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
```

What would the equation to solve RK3 look like? I.e. what would the value of the coefficients be for k1, k2 and k3 in this case be?

I can't find any examples of RK3 online, so sorry I have to ask this question...

Thanks!

Comment: its on wiki... [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge–Kutta_methods#Classic_fourth-order_method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Classic_fourth-order_method) Check out [Kutta's third order method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Kutta.27s_third-order_method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full step equation for the third order method is (in psuedo-code)

```
y[i+1] = y[i] + 1.0/6.0 * ( k1 + 4.0*k2 + k3 )

k1 = h * f(x[i], y[i])
k2 = h * f(x[i] + h / 2, y[i] + k1 / 2 )
k3 = h * f(x[i] + h, y[i] - k1 + 2 * k2 )
```